# Can you block a shot through the basket in basketball?

Tags: rules, basketball

If you block a ball from traveling all the way through the basket, by knocking it back through the hoop from the basket area, do you block the opponents team from scoring?

Answer (score 1):

Under [FIBA rules](http://www.fiba.basketball/OBR2017/Final.pdf), this is interference (Art 31.2.4):

> Interference occurs when:
>
> [...]
>
> - A player reaches through the basket from below and touches the ball

The penalty specified in Art 31.3 then applies, which is basically "the basket counts". NBA rules are effectively the same but with different wording.